# How to Pinpoint Unmatch Segment/Parse Between Two Paths Perl

Tags: perl, match

I have 2 paths that need to be compared, and if it is unmatch, I want to point out which sub-path or path that is not match. Is there any better way to do this? This is just for 2 path, I have a lot of paths that need to be compared.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $realPath= 'C/library/media/music/retro/perl.mp3'; #Absolute
my $comparedPath= 'music/classic/perl.mp3';           #Relative, a sample that need to be compare with the $realPath
my @compared_array;
my @realpath_array;
my %compared_hash;
tie %compared_hash, 'Tie::IxHash';
my %realpath_hash;
tie %realpath_hash, 'Tie::IxHash';


if ( $realPath=~ m/$comparedPath$/)
{
 print "$comparedPath exist";
}
else
{
 print "$comparedPath is not exist";
 @compared_array=split /\//,$comparedPath;
 @realpath_array=split /\//,$realPath;
}
@compared_hash{@compared_array}=1;
@realpath_hash{@realpath_array}=1;
foreach my $key (keys %compared_hash)
{
    delete $compared_hash{$key} if (grep {$_ =~/$key/} (keys %realpath_hash));
#leaving only unmatch Path Segment/Parse
}
print join("\n",%compared_hash);
```

Output:

```
classic
```

Comment: Can you show a sample of the input and the corresponding expected output? It's not clear what should happen if one of the paths is absolute and the second one is relative. Using a path as a regex seems wrong, too.

Comment: @choroba, I have update my question, does it answered your questions? yes, I feel that way too but I don't know if there is alternative simple method. just to check the 2 paths and print out if there is any mismatch.

Comment: Your algorithm outputs nothing for `music/media/perl.mp3`. Is it correct?

Comment: @choroba, yes indeed, because it takes the elements in `$comparedPath`, and then stored it in a hash `%compared_hash`,then compare it with another hash `realpath_hash` with the elements in `$realPath`, and if it is match, it will delete the keys in the `%compared_hash` leaving only unmatch keys, which is only `classic`

Comment: Please, check again. There's no `classic` involved in my comment, it compares `C/library/media/music/retro/perl.mp3` and `music/media/perl.mp3`.

Comment: @choroba, yes you are correct. I have misunderstood you, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

There's several ways they could compare.

- They don't overlap at all.
- They overlap, but one is too short.
- They partially overlap.
- They overlap perfectly.

Turn the paths into arrays using [File::Spec->splitpath and splitdir](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Spec). Then the problem becomes a matter of comparing arrays. It's also much simpler inside its own function because we can `return` as soon as we reach a conclusion.

First, we can use [List::MoreUtils::after_incl](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::MoreUtils#after_incl-BLOCK-LIST) to find the point where they start overlapping. In your example `@remainder` is `qw(music retro perl.mp3)`.

```
my @remainder = after_incl { $_ eq $rel_path->[0] } @$abs_path;
if( !@remainder ) {
    say "The paths do not overlap";
    return;
}
```

Then we can walk `@remainder` and the path together to find where they diverge. And we also need to make sure we don't walk off the path.

```
for my $idx (1..$#remainder) {
    if( $idx > $#$rel_path ) {
        say "The path is too short";
        return;
    }
    if( $remainder[$idx] ne $rel_path->[$idx] ) {
        say "The paths differ at $remainder[$idx] vs $rel_path->[$idx]";
        return;
    }
}
```

Finally, if they match we need to check if there's more on the end of the path.

```
if( @$rel_path > @remainder ) {
    say "The path is too long";
    return;
}
```

And if it passes all that, they overlap.

```
say "The path is a child";
return;
```

Put it all together...

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.10;

use List::MoreUtils qw(after_incl);

sub find_difference {
    my($abs_path, $rel_path) = @_;

    my @remainder = after_incl { $_ eq $rel_path->[0] } @$abs_path;
    if( !@remainder ) {
        say "The paths do not overlap";
        return;
    }

    for my $idx (1..$#remainder) {
        if( $remainder[$idx] ne $rel_path->[$idx] ) {
            say "The paths differ at $remainder[$idx] vs $rel_path->[$idx]";
            return;
        }
    }

    if( @$rel_path > @remainder ) {
        say "The path is too long";
        return;
    }

    say "The path is a child";
    return;
}

find_difference(
    [qw(library media music retro perl.mp3)],
    [qw(music retro perl.mp3 foo bar)]
);
```